# C++ Linked List creation

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

I was looking through the code for creating a linked list and almost everywhere I have observed that a function to add a node is given even if the number of nodes are known and then add operation for node is executed one by one for each element.

Why can't one simply create an array of nodes with new operator and assign the values from simple raw values array and just connect the links?

Something like this:

```cpp
Node* create_list(unsigned int n, unsigned int arr[]) {
    Node* head = new node[n];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        head[i].data = arr[i];

        if (i != n - 1)
            head[i].next = head[i + 1];
        else
            head[i].next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Is this a valid code to create a linked list from array?

Comment: In a linked list, the nodes are added and deleted independently from each other.  That's the point of using a linked list rather than some other structure.

Comment: Certainly one could do this. If one finds themselves *always* adding two nodes at a time, why make two calls vs. one call with two parameters? But generally linked list examples are going to be related to teaching data structures and work with the *basic* operations, not any specific additional use cases for one's problem domain.

Comment: If you are creating a linked list from an array then it nullifies the main advantage of a linked list, which are dynamic memory allocation and insertion-deletion operation in constant O(1) time complexity. And using an array to create a linked list also adds an extra memory overhead (space complexity will increase) which is not a good idea. Hope you got my point, thanks!

Comment: To `delete` one of those items you must find the first element in the array and `delete[]` them all. Could be very hard to do and almost certainly not what you want to do. That said, I do something similar in resource-constrained systems where memory fragmentation can be lethal. I will allocate an array of nodes, place those nodes in a linked list of free nodes, and when nodes are needed, users take a node from the free list and ad it to their own list. When they are done, the user places the node back in the free list. What happens when there are no free nodes left is up to the user.

Comment: @user4581301 why do a delete would be difficult? I have a head pointer and can easily fetch out pointer to other node and call delete.

Comment: You can only delete objects. The whole array is an object. Goofy as this may sound, the nodes inside the array are not objects. So you can `delete[] head;` and the whole array goes, taking all of the nodes with it. You cannot `delete &head[42];` to free one node. If you add more nodes to the list later, you will have no good way to tell which nodes were allocated with the array and which need to be `delete`ed separately. If the list gets shuffled around and a different node is now at `head`, `head` no longer holds the address of the array, so `delete[] head;` will fail. Lot of room for error.

Comment: [C++ definition of *object*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)

Comment: @logicseeker *Is this a valid code to create a linked list from array?* -- Linked lists back in the old days were done using arrays, but not in the way you are doing them.  The array would consist of a record, where each record contains 1) the data and 2) the next and previous indices.  For 2) The next and previous would be simple indices telling where the next and previous items are located in the array.  Get any data structures book that is more than 30 years old, and you see it described in detail.  This was the way it was done, since few languages back then had actual pointers.

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful to add your Node definition as well, but i think that can be inferred as having a next and data member / field.

What you've made is an array, where each element has a pointer to the next element in the array, and a data value.. could accomplish the same with an array of unsigned ints.

How do you add an element to the "linked list"? how do you remove it?
Try to understand the concept of a linked list in natural language before putting it to code.

As an aside, in your for-loop, you have a check that's false n-1 times and only true at the end.. could make the small optimization by doing that NULL assignment after the loop. as in:

```cpp
for (unsigned i = 0; i < n-1; ++i){
  head[i].data = arr[i] ;
  head[i].next = head[i+1]; // this is just extra space with a linked list as an array
}
head[n-1].data = arr[n-1];
head[n-1].next = NULL;
```

you're doing one assignment an extra time to save yourself a few lines of code and a condition checked n-1 times (compiler may optimize out)

Finally, once you do have a solid understanding of linked lists, avoid using raw pointers in C++, you have smart pointers available to you as a huge QoL upgrade from C.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-threaded embedded environment, it's pretty common to use arrays to do a one time creation of linked lists, which in turn are used as queues or stacks or pools of pre-allocated fixed sized objects. Example code:

```
NODE * CreateList(size_t count){
    NODE *pList;
    NODE *pNode;
    pList = new(std::nothrow) NODE[count]; // embedded code may have alternative to new
    if(!pList)
        return pList;
    pNode = pList;    // create list
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; i++){
        pNode->data = ...   // for empty pool, data usually not initialized
        pNode->next = pNode+1;
        pNode++;
    }
    (--pNode)->next = NULL;
    return pList;

// ...
DeleteList(NODE * pList){
    delete[] pList;
}
```

Comment: Using a linked list in this way seems like unnecessary churn.  Why not use the array directly?

Comment: @Spencer It's a case of pick and choose. Sometimes a linked list is the right data structure for the job. Especially in resource constrained environments like embedded systems where you don't usually get all the groovy bells and whistles that come "free" with a full-featured CPU.

Comment: Why isn't, say, a circular array feasible for a queue?

Comment: @Spencer - in a multi-threaded environment, those nodes from the array end up in multiple queues, so it's a space issue. A one time free queue is created along with one empty input queue per thread. All of the nodes used for queuing are allocated from and eventually returned to that free queue. Each queue has a mutex (ownership), and a semaphore (count). Something equivalent to Windows [wait for multiple objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) is used to wait for a non-empty queue and ownership in a single call.

Comment: @Spencer - the other case is a free pool queue of fixed sized objects, such as fixed size buffers. Buffers are allocated from and returned to the free pool queue, rather than using something like new or malloc. The message queue nodes may include a pointer to a buffer along with other data. Although these free pool type lists start off in a fixed order, the ordering changes over time depending on the order that nodes are returned to a free pool list.

Comment: @Spencer - to clarify the space issue, if using circular arrays, then one array per thread would be needed for the inter-thread message queuing. By using a single free pool message queue, only one array is needed for all threads.